# strange problem playing cocos2d animation from another class?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

strange thing. if someone could please,please help me. its 3 days, and i think i am going to be fired :(

i have cocos2d class with animation function,and another xcode class.
if i call from the cocos2d class init function to animation function, the animation is being played when app is starts.

if i call from another class to the cocos2d class-animation, so it does the init function and enter the animation,but i cant see it playing.

so the animation is working only if called from within the cocos class only.
WHY ?

this is how i call the animation :

```
ran=[[HelloWorld alloc] init];
    [ran animation];
```

this is the animation:

```
-(void)animation
{
    //[self removeChild:background cleanup:YES];
    //[b_pic.parent removeChild:b_pic cleanup:YES];



    //animation
    CCSpriteBatchNode *danceSheet = [ CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"head.png"]; 
    [self addChild:danceSheet];

    CCSprite *danceSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:danceSheet.texture rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];
    [danceSheet addChild:danceSprite];
    //danceSprite.anchorPoint=CGPointMake(0, 0);

    CGSize s = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    danceSprite.position = ccp(s.width/2,s.height/2);

    CCAnimation *danceAnimation = [CCAnimation animation];
    [danceAnimation setDelay:0.1f];

    int frameCount = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++) 
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",animation);
        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) 
        {
            CCSpriteFrame *frame = [CCSpriteFrame frameWithTexture:danceSheet.texture rect:CGRectMake(x*320,y*440,320,440)];
            [danceAnimation addFrame:frame];

            frameCount++;

            if (frameCount == 25)
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post HelloWorld init code. And where and how in init you are adding animation call to work.

Comment: the init is empty. it doesnt have anything in it only the self=[super init] , the animation is not in init, but just a method in that class. i call the animation method, on the cocos2d class, from another class. the nslog show me that it enter the animation,but not playing it. if i call the same animation from the init function like:[self animation]; its working. why is that ??

Comment: Can you call the animation function twice within that same class...Try [self animation]; and [[CCScheduler sharedScheduler] scheduleSelector:@selector(animation) forTarget:self interval:10 paused:NO]; and see if the animation gets called the second time.

Answer (score 0):

Can you call the animation function twice within that same class...Try

```
[self animation];
```

and

```
[[CCScheduler sharedScheduler] scheduleSelector:@selector(animation) forTarget:self 
interval:10 paused:NO];
```

and see if the animation gets called the second time.

If it doesn't which at this point I don't think it will, you should define all that you can in the init and then only run the pieces you need in the animation method (i.e. add the batchNode and Sprite in the init as ivars and reuse them in the animation).

Answer (score 0):

solved , and i dont know why.

but if you want to call a cocos2d function from the outside, you have to do  :

```
[(HelloWorld*)[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene] getChildByTag:42] HardwareEvent:DollPart];
```

and tag your layer like :

```
 layer.tag=42;
```

on the scene method !

thats the only way it works great.