# if( (self=[super init] ) )?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

why if i am trying to call animation function in cocos2d like this :

```
    -(id) init
    {
       if( (self=[super init] ) ) 
    {
    [self animation];

    }
        return self;
    }
```

its working great, but when i do this :

```
-(id) init
    {
      [self animation];
       if( (self=[super init] ) ) 
    {


    }
        return self;
    }
```

the animation is **called** but **not** being played ??? or i cant see it ??
i just cant understand that.

Answer (score 4):

It is natural that base class's `init` is doing something important that is required to run the animation. That's why when you are trying to run animation before calling `init` of base class animation is not playing.

Comment: ok thanks, but why when i call animation function in this class ,from another class, it fire the init again, and not playing the animation ???

Comment: Not sure what you are saying. Can you post the codes which is causing the problem? Which class is this? What is the base class? How you are calling animation from another class?

Comment: yes i post a question with details with no answer, i really need it:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710389/strange-problem-playing-cocos2d-animation-from-another-class

Comment: It's not a very good idea to post multiple questions on same topic. And sorry to say that the previous question is not in details. I have made a comment on that question too.

Comment: this seems a huge bag. its a week that we cant solve that. you just cant call animation of a cocos class from another class. just cant. you can call every other function in the cocos class and do anything else-such as show images and move things, but animation ? you just cant play if you call it from another class !!! if its from the same class so it can be done !   what is that !?? its driving me crazy !!

Comment: You want to run an animation from another class?  Do it outside of init if you are having trouble getting it to work inside init.  Set your animation to start inside a class method and call that method after the class has been instantiated.